# How to access the Wi-Fi password through Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, wifi, keychain

I am at my school and the computer I am currently using is connected to a Wi-Fi network. I want to know the Wi-Fi password and I am on a Mac. I know there is a way to do it through Terminal.

What I am using is:

```
security find-generic-password -ga  AirPort
```

I use that to find the password if it is in a keychain, but I know there is another way to do it. My friend who is a coder told me their is but they said they wont help me. All they told me was "generic" was a hint. I used "generic" in my command but I don't get it.

I tried your answer but it keeps asking my for the admin password. I am connected to the wifi but it still wont work. My coding friend looked at this and said I'm not looking for a AirPort password I'm looking for a regular password.

Comment: Prerequisite, you are the owner, with Admin password, you are or have been connected to the specific WiFi and the password is saved in keychain.

Answer (score 19):

```
security find-generic-password -D "AirPort network password" -a $SSID -g | grep "password:"
```

Replace `$SSID` with the SSID (the network name) of the network that you wish to obtain the key of.
This command looks for all keys with a type of "AirPort network password" and searches for the key with the name of the SSID that you provide.

Comment: I've added following two functions `wssid` and `wpass` in my `~/.zshrc` to detect current SSID and get the password for it. No need to set the `$SSID` variable. Also use the `-w` parameter instead of `-g` to show just the password. No need to grep it then...

`wssid () { /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I  | awk -F' SSID: '  '/ SSID: / {print $2}' ; }`

`wpass () { security find-generic-password -D 'AirPort network password' -a $(wssid) -w ; }` Sorry, can't add answer. Low reputation yet. Upvote would help ;)

Answer (score 17):

I think what you're actually looking for is this:

```
security find-generic-password -ga "ROUTERNAME" | grep "password:"
```

You'll get in response something like:

```
password: "ThePassword"
```

You can also use the flag `-w` to show only the raw password and avoid any extra `grep`, like so:

```
security find-generic-password -wga "ROUTERNAME"
```

Which in the above example would simply return:

```
ThePassword
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I have the MacBook connected to the WiFi but forget the password. help me a lot to retrieve the password and use the internet on the mobile.

Answer (score 2):

1. get the **SSID** of current wireless network (use `--getinfo`)

   ```
   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I

        agrCtlRSSI: -51
        agrExtRSSI: 0
       agrCtlNoise: -93
       agrExtNoise: 0
             state: running
           op mode: station 
        lastTxRate: 130
           maxRate: 217
   lastAssocStatus: 0
       802.11 auth: open
         link auth: wpa2-psk
             BSSID: 0:31:c2:41:53:14
              SSID: DansLeVille
               MCS: 15
           channel: 5
   ```

   But if you want to get all wifis in your area, (use `--scan`)

   ```
   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -s
                               SSID BSSID             RSSI CHANNEL HT CC SECURITY (auth/unicast/group)
                     America_Online 00:71:c2:9a:11:b0 -86  1       Y  US WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) 
                        xfinitywifi 00:71:c2:9a:11:b2 -72  1       Y  US NONE
                        xfinitywifi 84:00:2d:78:ee:ea -56  11      Y  US NONE
                              amber 74:1b:b2:d5:93:a9 -53  104     Y  US WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
                        xfinitywifi 74:85:2a:a9:f3:4a -66  11      Y  US NONE
                      HOME-1A17-2.4 74:85:2a:a9:f3:48 -66  11      Y  US WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) 
             Cooper Works Streaming 90:a7:c1:b9:6c:37 -50  11,-1   Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES,TKIP/TKIP) 
                              amber 74:1b:b2:d5:93:a8 -49  11      Y  US WPA2(PSK/AES/AES)
   ```

   2. get the password for wireless

      ```
      sudo security find-generic-password -D "AirPort network password" -a YOUR_SSID_NAME -g | grep password:
      password: "pseudononymous1234!!!"
      ```

   You see the `password:` at the end.

Comment: This is the same command I answered with over a year prior…?

Comment: when I type this command, I get exactly same output as shown BUT without password at the bottom. Do you know why?

Comment: @NS_777 is the wireless public network?

Comment: @prayagupd it is university library. can only be accessed if you are a student. each student has different username and password to access it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version of OS X the other answer or original question is for but it's not accurate on 10.10 Mavericks. You need this:

```
security find-generic-password -D "802.1X Password"
```

Maybe networks using actual Apple AirPort hardware are saved in the keychain Differently?

Comment: This shows passwords for networks using a different kind of authentication.

Answer (score 1):

This will display the SSID, password, and a QR code for your current WiFi network.

[image: Example QR Code]

Use this script to retrieve the current network's SSID, password, and generate a QR code for easy mobile access:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Get the current SSID
SSID=$(networksetup -getairportnetwork en0 | awk -F': ' '{print $2}')

# Retrieve the password
PASSWORD=$(security find-generic-password -D "AirPort network password" -wa "$SSID")

# Retrieve the security type
SECURITY=$(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I | awk -F': ' '/^ *Security/ {print $2}')

# Adjust the security type for the QR code
case "$SECURITY" in
  "WPA2 Personal") SECURITY="WPA";;
  "WEP") SECURITY="WEP";;
  "None") SECURITY="nopass";;
  *) SECURITY="WPA";;
esac

# Output network information
echo "SSID: $SSID"
echo "Password: $PASSWORD"
echo "Security: $SECURITY"

# Generate QR code for WiFi access
qrencode -t ANSIUTF8 "WIFI:T:$SECURITY;S:$SSID;P:$PASSWORD;;"
```

Please note that executing this script will require your user password for retrieving the WiFi password.

Save this script as `showpass` and make it executable with the command:

```sh
chmod +x showpass
```

Before running this script, ensure `qrencode` is installed. If not, install it using Homebrew:

```sh
brew install qrencode
```

Now you can run the script with:

```sh
./showpass
```