# security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: (Wi-Fi password via Terminal)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, mac, wifi

im trying to view (as root) wifi passwords in plaintext via Terminal[1] but get the following error:

```
sh-3.2# security find-generic-password -ga "ROUTER-NAME-HERE"
security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.

sh-3.2# security find-generic-password -a lily -s "ROUTER-NAME-HERE" -g
security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
```

so i googled the error[2] but i didnt find the answer helpful.

> [1] [How to access the Wi-Fi password through Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176119/how-to-access-the-wi-fi-password-through-terminal)
>
> [2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303755/keychain-security-command-line-tool-works-with-find-internet-passwords-but-not-f

```
sh-3.2# system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 12.5.0
      Boot Volume: lily
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: lily’s MacBook Air
      User Name: System Administrator (root)
      Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
      Time since boot: 12:37

sh-3.2# uname -a
Darwin lily-MacBook-Air.local 12.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display the WiFi password of a named wireless network exactly like this, replacing "wifinetworkname" with your wireless network name in quotes:

```
security find-generic-password -D "AirPort network password" -l "wifinetworkname" -w
```

Comment: ooh, i didnt realize we needed to use "AirPort network password" literally. i thought you were asking me to enter some password. thank you!